# Why are there two Chromes installed?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, installation, troubleshooting

I went to uninstall some stuff, and I just happened to notice something I hadn't notice before: that there are two Google Chromes installed. I thought at first this might have been a glitch or something weird, so I refreshed multiple times, but every time it was still there. Here's the (clickable) screenshot of when I checked at 2015-08-30T16:59 UTC.

[image: PF1]

Here's another (clickable) screenshot of it taken a few minutes later at 2015-08-30T17:03 UTC.

[image: PF2]

I checked Revo Uninstaller, too. Same thing. ((Clickable) Screenshot taken at 2015-08-30T17:06 UTC.)

[image: RL1]

At this point, I went straight to the `Programs (x86)` folder. Not entirely sure, but if I understand this stuff correctly then yeah that's two separate installs in the same folder. Am I right or wrong about this?

(Clickable screenshot)
[image: WinDir1]

---

**Specs**:

- *Make & Model*: HP Compaq dc5700 SFF
- *Operating System*: Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64
- *Chrome Version*: 44.0.2403.157 m (64-bit) (Installed¹)

- *Total Drive² Capacity*: 74.4 GiB (79.9 GB)
- *Remaining Drive Capacity*: 10.9 GiB (11.7 GB)
- *Drive Type*: HDD
- *RAM*: 2 GiB

---

¹ In other words, *not portable*.

² Drive E is just a 16 GB flash drive, so I'm not including that as I don't think that's really that relevant, if at all. I can add it if I'm wrong, so let me know if that's the case.

Comment: Based on the information provided one is likely the 32-bit installation you originally had before Chrome support 64-bit version.  The fact Chrome is installed in the 32-bit installation directory sort of proves this.

Comment: But I didn't choose to install either one. Google only provides a single, unified installer, and I assumed that therefore it would install the one that's most in line with my computer's bit architecture. (I.e., I have a 64-bit copy of Windows 7 installed, so it automatically installs the 64-bit version of Chrome. Or if I had the 32-bit copy of Win7 installed, it would automatically install the 32-bit version of Chrome.)

Comment: Either way, I always uninstall my programmes before I re-install them, so I don't see why it should have two installations.

Comment: And I use Revo Uninstaller, too, so it's not likely the uninstaller probably messed up or something...

Comment: 64-bit version of Chrome was only recently done in Aug.  Which is the reason I mentioned that.  64-bit versions of Chrome are not installed to the `Program Files (x86)` directory.

Comment: Well, I guess I must have made a mistake? Or could it have automatically installed the 64-bit version during a Chrome update?

Comment: You tell us.  Check both `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` a `Chrome` folder within the parent directory `Google` exists in both locations you have at some point installed the 64-bit version of Chrome.  This would not have happen by just performing an update.

Comment: Eh, it doesn't really matter. I was just curious, and was a bit concerned. But now that I know it's not really anything to worry about, I'm not really concerned much anymore. :P

Comment: Either way, could you please post one or more of your comments as an answer so I can mark it as Solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64-bit version of Chrome is always installed in `Program Files` and the 32-bit version of Chrome, on a 64-bit version of Windows, is always installed in `Program Files (x86)`.

If Chrome is being installed twice then you have both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of Chrome.  Since Chrome only recently started to offer a stable 64-bit version this easily could happen by mistake.

The simplest solution would be to uninstall both versions of Chrome and install only the 64-bit version of Chrome.  You can do that by running this [installer](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/?platform=win64)